# Question about homology groups of simplicial complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

> Let $K$ consist of all the faces of an oriented $n$-simplex (so that $\text{Vert}(K)$ is linearly ordered), and let $L$ be the subcomplex of all the proper subfaces (so that $|L| \approx S^{n-1}$), then $\tilde H_q(L) = \{0 \text{ if $q \neq n-1$}, \Bbb Z \text{ if $q = n - 1$}\}$

The proof construct a commutative diagram between $$0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow C_{n-1}(L) \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow C_0(L) \rightarrow C_{-1}(L) \rightarrow 0 \text{ and }$$ $$0 \rightarrow C_n(K) \rightarrow C_{n-1}(K) \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow C_0(K) \rightarrow C_{-1}(K) \rightarrow 0 \text{ and }$$

and then states that because $C_n(K) \approx \Bbb Z$, the exactness of the bottom row gives:

$$\Bbb Z \approx C_n(K) \approx \text{im}\space\partial_n=\ker \partial_{n-1}$$

**Why are $C_n(K)$ and $\text{im}\space\partial_n$ isomorphic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\partial_n:C_n(K)\to C_{n-1}(K)$ is a homomomorphism, it gives an isomorphism from $C_n(K)$ to its image as long as it is injective.  But injectivity of $\partial_n$ is just the exactness of the sequence $0\to C_n(K)\to C_{n-1}(K)$.  Concretely, the boundary of the unique $n$-simplex is just an alternating sum of distinct $(n-1)$-simplices and in particular is nonzero (as is any multiple of it by a nonzero integer).

Comment: That makes sense.  Just out of curiosity is there a generalization of that in terms of morphisms in category theory?

Comment: i.e. $f \in Hom_C(A,B)$ injectively means $\text{im} f $ is related via an equivalence to $A$?